# Python 3.6 does not run on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, python

Using Windows 10.

First I uninstall any existing versions of Python 3 or Python 2.0

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/python-3.6.0-amd64.exe

Then I run the above program, Windows seems to install it OK (I choose "Add Python 3.6 to the path"). I hit "Install now".

I run Windows Powershell.

I type python3 and nothing happens.

```
PS C:\Users\d> python
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable progr
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\d> python3
python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable pro
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python3
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\d>
```

Can anyone suggest what I can do to get Python 3.6 to install?

Comment: Why are you using a powershell command prompt to your python program called python. Also add the path to python to your system variable

Comment: @ramhound is that meant to be some sort of answer?

Comment: I can't answer a question that isn't clear.  You have multiple issues.  One your system variable doesn't include a path to the python installation directory and two your attempting to start "python" which wouldn't even work if you had the system variable right.

Comment: You should be able to add the python app location path to the PATH environmental variable in the Windows OS for this to work too as Ramhound suggested. I posted an answer for a method [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1112867/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-a-c-shell-without-specifying-whole-path/1116204#1116204) too .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who follow, in order to make Python work on Windows, it was not enough to select the default options during installation.

You MUST select custom - I don't know exactly which option I selected in custom but I installed to c:\python36 and installed for all users and told it to set the path and after that it worked.

Comment: Setting the path is the only thing you actually needed to do, I don't know why it's not enabled by default...