# Why python3/pip adds .exe to $env:path instead of .py on windows?

Tags: windows, python

When using pip to install a tool on windows, a .exe of the tool will be added to $python3_path\Scripts (that was added to $env:path by the python3 installer).

Why is it adding a .exe and not a .py as .py extension is registered to be launched with the python interpreter ?

Comment: Not 100%, but it is probably simply a support item associated with the package. Modules that have "command line" components have these stuck in the Scripts folder (this can be .exe files, .py files and shell/cmd scripts, not just .exe). Why it isn't a .py file is something to likely ask the developer.

Comment: Check out the answer I wrote up here that will help for sure... https://superuser.com/questions/1112867/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-a-c-shell-without-specifying-whole-path/1116204#1116204 The path should point the Python exe and the associations, ftype, etc. from the other path will help so you can execute any py script and it'll know to run with the python engine per the exe and the file extension.

Comment: I can already run python scripts from command line.