# How do I associate JPEG files on Windows 10 with IrfanView (or other program)?

Tags: windows-10, file-association, jpeg

I was trying to associate from within IrfanView options, but it didn't help.

When did this with "Run As Administrator", it didn't help either.

The right click menu doesn't contain "Use Always" checkbox any more:

[image]

Comment: What up @Dims.... Check out my answer here that can help you with this task step for step actually I think: https://superuser.com/questions/1112867/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-a-c-shell-without-specifying-whole-path/1116204#1116204. Just replace the `ASSOC` and the `FTYPE` command values to be that of the jpeg and irfanView app rather that Python and py file types if you know what I'm saying.... Let me know if this helps any and if you have any questions about that method to get the result.

Comment: Right click on a JPEG, select "associate..." submenu from the menu, there select "Select another program" option, then you will get same menu like on your picture, BUT there'll a checkbox with "always open with selected software". Tick it, choose the IrfanView, next time it will work automatically. ("labels" in my comment may not the exact words, just the meaning same, I'm using different language settings of Windows)

Comment: *'Right click menu doesn't contain "Use Always" checkbox anymore"*  Did this only happen recently, or has it always been that way?  That being said, it would probably help if you provided us with at least the minimum amount of pertinent information regarding your Windows 10 operating system:  Pro/Home/Enterprise/Education, Version 1607, 1703, or 1709, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Open Control Panel, type "Default Programs" in the search box, and click on the only search result, also "Default Programs".

Scroll down to "Choose default app by file type", wait for a while until it loads, and scroll down to jpg or jpeg, depending on your file extension. Click on the application currently listed, and it should provide you a list of applications to choose from. Select the application you desire, and you're all set.

Note, that if your machine is not your own (for example, a corporately owned workstation at your employer) this option MAY not be available to you.

Comment: Does not work in the newest Win 10 version. they let you change file assoc for jpeg, jp, png, etc but not for jpg. I HATE win10!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run iview.exe as administrator, set your associations, and then you can go to control panel, type associations, and it will then let you select iview as the default photo viewer. This even works with the portable version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you installed IrfanView previously and need to clean your registry because it's making wrong connections? That was my problem anyways. See here for more info:
http://www.braineating.com/2018/06/irfanviewsuckswithwindows10.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed very frustrating.

- Choose another app does not show checkbox
- Choose Default Apps by file type, does not show InfranView
- Rightclick on the JPG file, properties Opens With [Change...] button does not appear

I really hope this is a bug and not a microsoft push for their Photo viewer.
I tried to set the associations from infranView but it failed, because in windows 10, there is a "feature" that prevents apps from changing it.

Luckily there is a tool for you:

[SetUserFTA](http://kolbi.cz/blog/2017/10/25/setuserfta-userchoice-hash-defeated-set-file-type-associations-per-user/)

SetUserFTA .jpg IrfanView.JPG

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing the Windows App version of Irfanview, which automatically added it to the menu as a choice.