# Edit file extension/file type descriptors in Windows with Batch

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, batch

So, is there a Batch command that changes the text in the "Type" column in explorer for an .exe.

for example, .bat files are known as "Windows Batch File" in the type. I want to make a .disk files Type "Bulk Data Storage File", using Batch.

Is there a way?

Comment: See if my answer here helps but change the values accordingly for your needs.... https://superuser.com/questions/1112867/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-a-c-shell-without-specifying-whole-path/1116204#1116204

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT does that set a chosen text into `HKCR\.disk` (default)?

Answer (score 1):

To add a new extension to "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" you will need to run `reg.exe` with elevated rights.
It is the `(default)` value to set with the `/ve` switch and `/t REG_SZ`

```
reg.exe add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.disk" /ve /t REG_SZ  /d "Bulk Data Storage File"
```

If you want to change a present value append `/f` force

You will need to close/reopen explorer windows to take this into effect.

[image]

The following batch will elevate itself and 
ask for confirmation if the value exists - displaying old/new contents.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\16\SU_1331760.cmd
@Echo off& setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
:: elevate if neccessary
net file 1>nul 2>&1 || (powershell -ex unrestricted -Command ^
"Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath '%comspec%' -ArgumentList '/c %~f0 %*'"
  goto :eof)
:: Put code here that needs elevation

Set "Key=HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.disk"
Set "Dat=Bulk Data Storage File"
Set "Typ=REG_SZ"
Set "OLD="

:: reed present value, and ask for confirmation
for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (
'REG QUERY "%Key%" /VE ^|find /I "REG_SZ" '
) Do Set "OLD=%%C"
If defined OLD (
    Echo=
    Echo do you want to replace:
    Echo Old:%OLD%
    ECHO New:%Dat%
    Echo=
    Choice
    If errorlevel 2 exit /B 1
)
Echo REG ADD "%Key%" /ve /t %Typ%  /d "%Dat%" /f
     REG ADD "%Key%" /ve /t %Typ%  /d "%Dat%" /f
Pause
```

Comment: Is it necessary to add powershell? The elevated per issuing can also be checked with `%errorlevel%`.

Comment: The powershell part doesn't test elevation, but restarts the batch elevated.